# How come my UDP6 port was not listened in my net-snmp?

Tags: snmp

My Net-Snmp version was v5.9.3. It works fine basically except it doesn't serve IPv6. I used 'netstat --uln' and found only 'udp   :::161', but no 'udp6 :::161'. It's obviously that it listens only at udp:161, not at udp6:161.

My .../etc/snmp/snmpd.conf contains:

```
rocommunity xxxx localhost

rocommunity public

rocommunity6 public

agentaddress udp:161,udp6:161
```

What did I still miss for making my SNMP Daemon to listen to both UDP & UDP6? What tools or any ways can help me to figure it out?

ps. My kernel is 5.13.x and it's not pure Ubuntu because it's embedded Linux.

Comment: The version of Ubuntu and the kernel version may provide clues to your problem. Please use edit and add this info to the question.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Your kernel details don't match up with a supported system; Ubuntu Core & Ubuntu Server do support embedded systems*

Comment: > t's not pure Ubuntu < If this is not Ubuntu or an officially recognized flavor of Ubuntu, then this is offtopic here and we will not be able to assist you.